# Prime31 socialplugin iOS - How to attach and share picture already stored in my assets?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, filesystems, prime31

Prime 31 SocialPlugin question.

How do I attach and share picture already stored in my assets? I understand all the code but I'm not sure about the file path to the picture within the assets.

In the demo the plugin shares a screenshot taken in the beginning. This work correctly in my game.

```
    protected override void OnButtonTap ()
    {

        base.OnButtonTap ();

    #if UNITY_IPHONE
        var pathToImage = ????? // what here??

        if( !System.IO.File.Exists( pathToImage ) )
        {
            Debug.Log( "there is no screenshot avaialable at path: " + pathToImage );
            return;
        }
        SharingBinding.shareItems( new string[] { pathToImage, "Description" } );
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Attach it to what? Share it with what? I see you're using the prime31 tag. What exactly are you using? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: @Bart I updated question. It's prime31 social plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple in fact.

All you need is to put your prepared image you want to share to StreamingAssets folder (create it in Assets folder if you don't have one)
And change `Application.persistentDataPath` to `Application.streamingAssetsPath`

That's it.

```
#if UNITY_IPHONE
    var pathToImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, screenshotFilename);
    if( !System.IO.File.Exists( pathToImage ) )
    {
        Debug.Log( "there is no screenshot avaialable at path: " + pathToImage );
        return;
    }
    SharingBinding.shareItems( new string[] { pathToImage, "Amazing app for your kids. Check it out." } );
#endif
```

Comment: hello @alexhajdu, is this code also ok for android? how do you manage android?